# Auto-scrolling to the top of the page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scroll to top button fixed at the bottom-right of my page. When it's clicked, all I want is to scroll top of the page.

Now, What I tried:

```
  window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

```
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  })
```

```
 document.body.scrollTop = 0
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
```

```
document.querySelector('header').scrollIntoView({
 behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"
})
```

all of these works at first but as I scroll down, they scroll up the page a little bit and then stop. they don't go up.

Why might it be?

PS: I use chrome

Comment: Use window.scrollTo

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that into the question. I've also tried it but same. I feel like It should be something related to my css code but I am not sure where to look

Comment: Is it definitely the window that is being scrolled, rather than some child element? A [mre] of the issue would be very helpful here.

Comment: This happens when something scrolls it to another point while the scroll-to-top is still in progress. Remove the smoothness temporarily, to see the immediate jumps, find the culprit and then put it back.

Comment: @dkellner problem is solved. I posted the answer. thanks for the direction, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @dkellner 's comment I thought that it might related to smooth behavior,

When I searched it through my css code I found out that I had this line:

```
* {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

I changed it to

```
html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

and problem is solved.

I know giving all elements scroll-behavior: smooth don't make sense but I really like to know why it causes such an issue.

Comment: Not sure why THIS solved the problem, but we all learned a lot today :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to smoothly scroll to the top of the page when the "scroll to top" button is clicked. To prevent interference with the fixed button's positioning, you can temporarily disable the button's position: fixed property while scrolling, and then re-enable it afterward.

```
const scrollToTopButton = document.getElementById('scrollToTopButton'); 

scrollToTopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollToTopButton.style.position = 'static'; 

  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    scrollToTopButton.style.position = 'fixed'; // Re-enable fixed positioning after scrolling
  }, 1000); // Adjust the timing as needed
});
```